# Lucene: replicated (FS)Directory implementation

Tags: replication, lucene.net, lucene

Is there any alternative implementations of Lucene's (FS)Directory, notably ones related to replication? What I am looking forward to doing (but looking for something existing before implementing my own :) is a directory that    writes to multiple identical directories at the same time. The idea behind is that I can't deploy DFS or SAN and thinking of a sort of a "manual" replication to another node with the minimum possible delay. Thoughts?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually people use [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) for this. If you can't use Solr's replication functionality, you can do what people did before Solr: rsync your directories.